# Will AudioContext based libraries stop working after Chrome 55 update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-audio-api

I have a few Chrome extensions that rely on the Web Audio API, using a few libraries for recording and playing audio.

The Chromium blog [states](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/10/chrome-55-beta-input-handling.html) that:

> `BaseAudioContext` will replace `AudioContext` in the Web Audio API to conform to spec.

I have tested my extensions on Chrome Canary and it seems to be working, but I'm guessing that the Web Audio API wasn't updated yet so it might change.

Does anyone know if this is the case, and if simply renaming `AudioContext` to `BaseAudioContext` will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  BaseAudioContext is sub-classed by AudioContext and OfflineAudioContext.

https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#BaseAudioContext

Your code won't need to change.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!